# How to "pull" data from c++ to qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qqmlcomponent

I want "pull"data from c++ in qml like this:

```
   Component.onCompleted: {
        MySettings.loadMainWindowPosition(aAppWnd.x, aAppWnd.y, aAppWnd.width, aAppWnd.height, aAppWnd.visibility);
    }
```

When MySettings registered in the following way:

```
context->setContextProperty("MySettings", m_settings);
```

But when I make the funtion signature like this:

```
void MySettings::loadMainWindowPosition(int& x, int& y, int& width, int& height, int& visibility)
```

I received the following error:

> qrc:/GUI/App.qml:35: Error: Unknown method parameter type: int&

So how correctly "pull" data inside qml from c++?

**UPDATE**:

I explain better. Now I can call the c++ function (and send params) from qml:

```
   Component.onCompleted: {
        MySettings.someFunc(111, 222);
    }
```

In c++ code I receive function call with params values "111" and "222".

But I want change this parameters in c++. I want smth like that:

```
   Component.onCompleted: {
        var a;
        var b;
        MySettings.someFunc(a, b);
    }
```

I want set up in the c++ code params to the "333" and "555". So after call *MySettings.someFunc(a, b)* I expected that (a==333) and (b==555).

How to do this?

Comment: You cannot pass a reference, this type isn't supported in js. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html) for more info. Pass an object with properties instead and so update it in QML.

Comment: @folibis could you please provide some example? I read your link but didnt get how to call c++ function that return values in params from qml :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to get the return values as reference parameters when calling C++ functions from QML. Instead, use return values. To transfer more than one value in a single call, define your C++ method like

```
Q_INVOKABLE QVariantList someFunc() { ... }
```

and use it in QML via

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    var returnValues = MySettings.someFunc();
    //access the returnValues via list indices here:
    var a = returnValues[0];
    var b = returnValues[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing values ​​by reference do not work calling c ++ functions from QML. If you want sync calls, use something link this in your c ++ code:

```
QVariantList MySettings::someFunc(int a, int b){

        QVariantList list;
        list.append(a + 5); // edit the passed values here
        list.append(b + 5); // edit the passed values here
        return list;
    }
```

and something like this in your QML code:

```
var test = gapi.someFunc(3,2); // pass values here and get the new ones
console.log("The return data" + test);
```